# What to do with redundant index

Tags: mysql

I have tried making two database tables `wp_marketing` and `wp_email`. I have a problem of `redundant indexes` in these tables. I have added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`.

```
CREATE TABLE `cur_emailcontent` (
`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`message` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`mail_from` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
KEY `title` (`title`),
CONSTRAINT `cur_emailcontent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`title`) REFERENCES `cur_marketing` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Initially i made `title` column as `primary`, then I changed the `Index Type` of the same to `INDEX`. Now I can use any other `column` to be as `PRIMARY KEY` but I cannot delete this `index` using `PHPMyAdmin` but was unable to do so.I got to know that these types of `indexes` are called `redundant indexes`.

Now I don't have any option other than creating the `table(s)` again. Is there any solution to such indexes?

Comment: You lost me at *I have a common problem in these tables.*

Comment: @buzzinga: Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` in the question.

Comment: You have only one index, on `(title)`, so there shouldn't be any problem defining other indexes or a `PRIMARY KEY` (which you don't have now).

Comment: @ypercube i have added the output.

Comment: If you are trying to delete the above index, it should not allow you to, because of the foreign key constraint.

Comment: will it work after he drops the `Foreign-Key` constraint?

Comment: but i want to add `mail_from` as `primary key` now and delete this `index`. But I am not able to do that.

Comment: @DoSparKot Dropping the `foreign key constraint` isn't working.

Comment: `alter table cur_emailcontent drop foreign key cur_emailcontent_ibfk_1 ;` and then `alter table cur_emailcontent drop key title;` then `alter table cur_emailcontent add primary key (mail_from);`

Comment: Or in a single go `alter table cur_emailcontent drop foreign key cur_emailcontent_ibfk_1, drop key title, add primary key (mail_from);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If querying `cur_emailcontent` table based on `title` is very unlikely and don't want it to be a foreign key either; also to have `mail_from` as new primary key just execute:

```
ALTER TABLE cur_emailcontent DROP FOREIGN KEY cur_emailcontent_ibfk_1,
DROP KEY title,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (mail_from);
```

[MySQL Alter Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: I already dropped the `foreign key` but when I am `drop`ping the `key title`, it says : #1553 - Cannot drop index 'title': needed in a foreign key constraint

Comment: make sure `foreign key` constraint is dropped by checking the table schema (`show create table cur_emailcontent;`)

Comment: i checked, but it just show one `key`, i.e. `title`. And when i try dropping it, it doesn't due to `foreign key constraint`, which actually doesn't show up schema!